# How to do SQL query performance optimization perfect

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying to write a SQL script to fetch data for a specific date range. In the example shown below I am trying to pull data for 1 day (datetime) only.

But it just take more than 3 mins to complete the query execution.

I am not quite sure if I am missing any indexes to create on `Datetime` column. If yes could anybody please suggest me how to make this SQL query a quick execution?

Please also see the snapshots attached from query execution plan and statistics IO.

Thank you very much for your help.

**The SQL query**

```
set Statistics IO on
declare @StartDate datetime,@EndDate datetime
set @StartDate = '2012-07-19 00:00:00.000'
set @EndDate = '2012-07-20 23:59:00.000'
select * from Admin_Letters A with (nolock)
Where A.Date_Linked > @StartDate and A.Date_Linked < @EndDate
```

**The Execution plan snapshot(s)**

### **1.**

[image]

### **2.**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a `SELECT *` in your query, you will not have much luck trying to optimize anything.... since you request **all columns** from the table, SQL Server's query optimizer will often go for a table scan since that's just quicker.

Also: `table scan` implies that you don't have any clustering index on your table --> horribly bad choice. You should have a **good clustering index** on every real table!

Once you have that (on e.g. an `INT IDENTITY` column), then you need to decide **which columns** you really need from that table. Put a nonclustered index on `Date_Linked`, and include all those columns you really truly need - something like:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX01_Admin_Letters
ON dbo.Admin_Letters(Date_Linked)
INCLUDE (Col1, Col2, ..., ColN)   -- as **few** columns as possible!
```

and then a

```
SELECT Date_Linked, Col1, Col2, ...ColN 
FROM dbo.Admin_Letters A
WHERE A.Date_Linked > @StartDate AND A.Date_Linked < @EndDate
```

**will really fly!** (because now, SQL Server's query optimizer can choose to just pick a few rows from the index - and even an index scan, on a few columns, will be lots faster than a table scan)

Comment: OMG that is fantastic. My apologies i actually needed 3 columns from this table. And as per marc_s suggestion i have created nonClustered Index on Date_Linked including the column names which i needed. Now query just exectues very quickly. Now it just took 2 secs to execute. Thanks so very much Marc_S. So kind of you suggesting me good answer so quickly.